# How to programmatically save an OPEN Excel Document

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007

I have UI tests. When the UI tests finish, they open the result files in an Excel document (Excel 2007 is installed on the test environment) - but the problem is that the excel document is not saved anywhere on the computer. They exist only when the AutoRecover feature saves the temporary files as a .xar file, so this is useless to us.

We use a C# .NET program to launch the UI tests (and do a bunch of other things), so I'm looking to see if it's possible to save this OPENED excel document programmatically.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may help you [How to: Save Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Example

This example creates a new workbook, prompts the user for a file name, and then saves the workbook.

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Do
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
Loop Until fName <> False
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
```

Comment: Yep, this will work as long as he has a handle to the running excel application (which I imagine he would).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Can you re-write this in C# .NET? In the web page you linked to, they make use of the 'this' keyword, but how is this supposed to work? I want the code to save an excel document to be part of a C# .NET automation program... I tried putting together some code and used the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel DLL reference but I wasn't able to figure out how to use it to save documents using the MDSN documentation. Would you be able to provide more information? Thanks

Comment: @user606602: This is a very simple example to read, save an excel file http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/5443/

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks, but the code in the article does not really help, and I don't think it's simple. For example, take a look at the code for saving: 

'object objOpt = Missing.Value; objBook.SaveAs(newFilePath, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);' 

What is this Missing class for example? This doesn't make sense to me. Have you ever tried this yourself?

Comment: @user606602: It is in `System.Reflection` namespace and it just tell that object is missing or not available.

Comment: Hi, currently I have this code: 

`Application application = new Application();
 Workbooks workbooks = application.Workbooks;
 workbooks[0].SaveCopyAs("C:\\Book1.xlsx");` The application and workbooks objects are populated with data when the program is run, but it doesn't seem to pick up any workbooks, as it says the index is invalid. I have MS Excel opened on my computer - should it not be populated with any open workbooks on when I run this program?